# When is the {$new_status}_{$post->post_type} transition hook fired?

Tags: hooks

Is it fired after a post has been published?

Say I have a CPT and want to perform some automated actions based on the post that gets saved, can I do:

```
    add_action('publish_myt_cpt', 'myfunction');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is fired in `wp-includes/post.php` on line 3026
in the following function:

wp-includes/post.php: line 3014-3027

```
function wp_transition_post_status($new_status, $old_status, $post) {
    do_action('transition_post_status', $new_status, $old_status, $post);
    do_action("{$old_status}_to_{$new_status}", $post);
    do_action("{$new_status}_{$post->post_type}", $post->ID, $post);
}
```

Comment: So is that after the post has been saved?

Comment: 90% sure: Yes. You can check by dumping the contents of `$post` in the `add_action`. Or add a `die('check')` in the `add_action` and check the DB when the die hits

Comment: Right, the post is saved alright, but the post meta isn't yet saved at that point. What I need is to use one of the post meta fields, so I'm stuck.

Comment: Well that wasn't your original question. Accept my answer and make a new question or update this one.

Comment: In WordPress 3.5.2 its still in 'wp-includes/post.php', only its moved to line 3270. Up-vote for you sir @janw!